# How to find out which process eats up memory?

Tags: macos, memory, memory-leak

My MacBook Pro has 8G RAM. Recently memory leak offen happened. Page outs and swap used kept increasing. The last time it used ~8G swap space.

But in Activity Monitor, I can't find any process has a large value in 'Real Mem', 'Private Mem' nor 'Shared Mem' column.

I checked the %MEM column in output of 'ps -ev', all processes occupied less than 1% of memory. The full output is put in this gist: https://gist.github.com/aleung/4760556

What the way to diagnose OSX memory leak issue?

Comment: The %mem statistic seems to be ... weird. I can't figure out what it's a percentage of. Try `ps -axv` instead, and take a look at the RSS (resident memory in KB) and VSZ (virtual memory, also KB) columns.

Comment: Memory leak might be caused by Isolator.app. Since I removed this app, free memory > 3G for a few days. But this question is still valid, because seeing the output from both Activity Monitor and `ps -axv`, Isolator.app used not too much memory.

Comment: I am in a similar situation, and would also like to know the answer.
Perhaps we should look in the console and system logs.

Answer (score 1):

Check with this command (will show more processes):

```
sudo ps -awxm -o %mem,rss,comm | sort -nr | head
```

if won't help, check with `fs_usage` to display system calls and page faults related to filesystem:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys,diskio
```

especially page in and out by appending the following to above command:

```
| egrep -i "page_|pgin|pgout"
```

<sup>Add extra `| grep -v kernel` to ignore kernel process or `| grep -v 0.00` to show these with higher time spent.</sup>

If your swap is big, you can force disk cache to be flushed and emptied by: `sudo purge`.

Based on my experience, OS X have some issues with managing the memory after higher uptime (when it used all of free memory), so sometimes only full restart may help.

Check also `sudo iotop` or `sudo vm_stat 1` commands which may help.

See also: [How to investigate high kernel task memory usage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/178281/22781)